# View work space question

Tags: list-view

[image: screenshot]

In above screen shot, what is the "technical terminology" of the section in which view names are listed, as shown in red box.

Is it called "view work space"? So, if I'm working in a document library would it be called a document work space view? OR a task list? OR  task list view work space?

Comment: Multiple views?

Comment: I love the big red box AND arrows for clarity.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, it is your "list of Views". In the CSS that renders it, Microsoft uses the ID "WPQ2_ListTitleViewSelectorMenu_Container"; so you could refer to it as the "List View Selector Menu". (In libraries, it would be your "Library View Selector Menu".)